# What to do if action button and form fields are in different sections?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Let's say we have an edit form to create a new user. Now the save button is placed in a different section, the footer.

My problem is that I can't get the edit fields and the save button in one form, because the button is in a different section.

Because of that, I can't submit the form.

What is the best approach to this problem?

_Layout.cshtml

```
<div class="content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
<div class="footer">
    @RenderSection("Footer")
</div>
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section Footer
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h2>New User</h2>
    @Html.EditorForModel()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for my problem. It's not nice, but it works.

I replaced the submit button with an anchor. When the anchor is clicked, a javascript function gets called.

```
<a name="save" onclick="submitAction(this)"></a>
```

The javascript function creates a hidden submit button in the form and clicks it.

```
function submitAction(sender) {
    var action = $(sender).attr('name');
    $('form').append('<input type="submit" style="display:none" id="tmpSubmit" />');
    $('#tmpSubmit').attr('name', action);
    $('#tmpSubmit').click();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could call `form.Dispose()` explicitly, instead of the `using` statement:

```
@{ var form = Html.BeginForm() }

<h2>New User</h2>
@Html.EditorForModel()

@section Footer
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    @{ form.Dispose(); }
}
```

**Edit**

But you have to at least make sure the Body and Footer section are in the same container, for example:

```
<div class="content">
    @RenderBody()
    <div class="footer">
        @RenderSection("Footer")
    </div>
</div>
```

With the layout as written in the question, the `content` div (and therefore the `form` tag) must close before the `submit` button can ever appear.  There's no way this can work logically:

```
<div class="content">
    @RenderBody()               @@ form opens, and therefore must close here
</div>
<div class="footer">
    @RenderSection("Footer")    @@ submit button is here -- can never be inside the form
</div>
```

<sub>**Editorial aside:**  It seems like a very bad idea to have a form split across multiple partial views.  You might call it a code smell -- I'd try to avoid it if possible.</sub>

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. The end tag won't be rendered. Even if it would render the end tag, I think it would be invalid markup.

Comment: @JonathanEgerton yes, I noticed after posting my answer.  For this to work you'll have to move around the tags so that the `footer` is a child of the `body` section.

Answer (score 1):

You found a pretty awkward work around. I suggest doing it this way:

- In order to distinguish actions of different buttons clicked, create a new property in your model: `public string Action { get; set; }`
- Give you form an id and include a hidden input for your new model property.

```html
<form id="my-form">
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Action)
    ...
</form>
```

- Create buttons in the footer, with the same class, but different values:

```html
<button class="btn-submit" value="action1">Submit</button>
<button class="btn-submit" value="action2">Submit</button>
```

- Use the following JavaScript:

```js
$('.btn-submit').live('click', function() {
    // update value of hidden input inside the form
    $('#Action').val($(this.val()));
    // submit the form
    $('#my-form').submit();
});
```

- In your ActionResult perform different actions based on the value of Action property:

```cs
public ActionResult WahteverAction(WhateverModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(model.Action == "action1")
        {
            // do whatever needs to be done for action1
        }
        if(model.Action == "action2")
        {
            // do whatever needs to be done for action2
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: What happens if I have multiple buttons? How do I distinguish which button was clicked?

Comment: Please provide more information on why do you need to distinguish. Are these buttons performing different actions or are they submitting the same form?

Comment: Yes. The buttons are submitting the same form and perform different actions.